# "Save as PDF..." in Safari submenu

Tags: safari, pdf

Is it possible to place the "Save as PDF…" button from the print menu underneath the "Print…" button in the "File/print…" menu in safari?

Comment: Now there exists option "Export As PDF...".

Comment: In 2022, there is nothing like that in the menu, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether it is *possible* to modify the Safari user interface, the answer is clearly yes, but if the question is whether there is a straightforward way to modify the contents of menus in an Apple-shipped program, the answer is sadly, no, not without deep hacking.

There are workarounds, however. A Safari extension could be written to add an item to the Toolbar or to a context menu, although not to the menubar. Writing that extension would be a developer question beyond the scope of this site.

An automator service that calls an AppleScript to save the current page as PDF could be added to the **Safari** menu (not the File menu) and assigned a keyboard shortcut.

As far as I am aware, however, adding a command to the **File** menu is not possible through the standard (i.e. supported) extension mechanism, and would require hacking the Safari binaries.